# Why is the expression 'in car' possible instead of 'in the car'?

Tags: articles

I want to know the difference between in car and in the car.
Please, tell me.

Comment: The collocation **in car** normally occurs as a (hyphenated) adjectival usage. Thus, ***In-car entertainment** applies to electronic equipment which provides **entertainment in the car.***

Answer (score 1):

We don't say "in car". That would be incorrect. We could say "in a car" or "in the car". Here the difference would be that "the" would refer to a specific car which the listener knows either from something said earlier in the conversation or from some other contextual information. "A car" could be any car.

There are other certain idiomatic expressions that leave out "a", such as "He is at school," "He is at work," and "He is at home," etc. I guess these are special. We would say "He is at a restaurant," "He is in a car," and "He is in a store," etc.